# Simple way to keep track of MySQL change history?

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, redis, backup

I would like to have a record of all the changes(insert/update/delete) in my MySQL database.

Potentially I would also want this record to be easily executable, i.e. it can be use as a backup tool somehow if I choose to execute all the recorded statements.

My understanding is, the logs format by MySQL would probably contain unnecessary stuff and I would need extra processing to make the statements bulk executable.

Is creating a simple text file and write the SQL statements to it a good idea? Or is there some native functionalities in MySQL that already support this? Or is that a way I can make use of other software like redis to create a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 2):

> *"My understanding is, the logs format by MySQL would probably contain unnecessary stuff and I would need extra processing to make the statements bulk executable."*

That makes sense when you are talking about `MySQL General Log`.

With `MySQL Bin Log` you don't need to convert log format.

##First check out binlog_format##

There are 3 sort of `binlog_format`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-setting.html

with `STATEMENT` based binlog you can get INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE/etc statement for

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

##GET UPDATE statement using mysqlbinlog##

with `mysqlbinlog` and mysql binary log file, you can get update statement as follows:

```
$ mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000002
# at 2112
#131223 19:48:48 server id 1  end_log_pos 2233  Query   thread_id=1     exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1387795728/*!*/;
DELETE ... /* generated by server */
/*!*/;
# at 2233
#131223 19:48:48 server id 1  end_log_pos 2352  Query   thread_id=1     exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1387795728/*!*/;
INSERT .... /j* generated by server */
/*!*/;
# at 2352
#131223 19:48:48 server id 1  end_log_pos 2468  Query   thread_id=1     exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1387795728/*!*/;
DROP  /* generated by server */
```

##options for mysqlbinlog##

Here are some options related how to get logs of certain date (or position)

```
  --start-datetime=name
                      Start reading the binlog at first event having a datetime
                      equal or posterior to the argument; the argument must be
                      a date and time in the local time zone, in any format
                      accepted by the MySQL server for DATETIME and TIMESTAMP
                      types, for example: 2004-12-25 11:25:56 (you should
                      probably use quotes for your shell to set it properly).
  -j, --start-position=#
                      Start reading the binlog at position N. Applies to the
                      first binlog passed on the command line.
  --stop-datetime=name
                      Stop reading the binlog at first event having a datetime
                      equal or posterior to the argument; the argument must be
                      a date and time in the local time zone, in any format
                      accepted by the MySQL server for DATETIME and TIMESTAMP
                      types, for example: 2004-12-25 11:25:56 (you should
                      probably use quotes for your shell to set it properly).
  --stop-position=#   Stop reading the binlog at position N. Applies to the
                      last binlog passed on the command line.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try maxwell daemon (https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) which can effectively look at the binlog and generate change data in JSON format. I am using this to process the update journals for so long. It is a very stable solution I highly suggest.